# Detecting current subscriptions Apple IAPs IAP / Detect app deletion - Swift Firebase IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, in-app-purchase

I am making an app where someone subscribes - with a monthly Apple IAP - and receives exclusive content from an influencer. Once the user subscribes for the monthly plan their account in firebase firestore adds a field "Following": Influencer.

To see how many followers an influencer has I just loop through users and calculate how many people have their name in the "Following" field.

**Flow of App**

1. User subscribes to monthly IAP
2. Update "Following": Influencer field in Firebase for influencer
3. Count amount of people following influencer by looping through collection in Firebase

My issue is how can I detect if a user has deleted the app and unsubscribed? Ignoring this would overstate the follower count for the influencer.

Warm Regards and your help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can use the server to server API from apple to receive updates when a subscription is renewed or cancelled

Comment: A totally off topic comment but this *loop through users* is a bit scary. If you've got 100,000 users, that could take a while. Would it be possible to add a node to the influences that tracks follower count? +1 when a new follower is added and -1 when removed? That would avoid long delays. The bigger question is; does deleting the app really mean the user is no longer a follower? Suppose they did that to conserve space on their device or the they decided that wanted to delete it off their iPhone and use the app on another device. Expand on that - what if they want to use it on 3 devices?